# Kubernetes: Petset Cassandra in multiple DC

Tags: cassandra, dns, kubernetes

I successfully create Cassandara Petset on Kubernetes cluster in AWS. While, this is a single DC Cassandra cluster. Thinking of adding multiple DC support for cassandra. Say, have one kubernetes cluster in US west, one in US east, one in Europe. I'd like to have cassandra installed on each of those DCs and be able to replicate data between those 3 clusters.
The question I have no answer is how to let cassandra petset node in US West know another cassandra petset node in Europe? Before the DNS are connected, they can't parse each other's DNS name, right? Anyone had experience on it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take in consideration the Snitch, Seed Provider and Topology Strategy for Kubernetes, so the nodes are aware of their geographical location and guarantee that copies of the data are set up in all the regions; for this you should have a replication factor that will ensure enough copies.

There is already a project to integrate with Kubernetes [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24286) but they mention it is still experimental.

Finally, when working with different geographical locations, latencies can be a killer, it is always advisable to use for those cases local consistencies (i.e. LOCAL_QUORUM, LOCAL_ONE, LOCAL_SERIAL)